# Series of product counterexample

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I get the sense that this statement is false, but I am having trouble finding a counterexample:

> If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_{n+1}$ converges, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n$ converges.

Could you please offer a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you find two sequences so that every term in the first sum is zero but that that is not the case in the second sum?

Comment: @user150160: Yes it does.

Comment: @rogerl Thank you for the excellent hint! It looks like $a_n = b_n = 1 + (-1)^n$ will do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{a_n\}$ with $a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $a_{2n}=0$ and $\{b_n\}$ with $b_{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $b_{2n+1}=0$

The the first series is zero while the second one is $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: More complicated than it needs to be - $a_{2n+1}=1/n$ and $b_{2n}=1$ is easier.